# Named SVG FIlter in Electron

Tags: css, svg, electron

Using a named SVG filter in Electron will not work and produces a 404 Resource not found.

```
div.someClass{ filter: url('#theSVGFilter'); }
```

The SVG section is located inline in the same html file where the css class is being applied.

```
<svg>
    <filter id="theSVGFilter">
        ...
    </filter>
</svg>
```

Electron looks for the #theSVGFilter using the file protocol. Is there a way to define a protocol for local anchors?

Comment: Hi, there! Did you find a solution?

Comment: I ended up inlining the svg filters directly into the css using data uris. This site helps in producing them: http://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php